# numpy.fft custom range and number of frequencies

Tags: python, audio, fft

In my code (below) numpy.fft.rfft(signal) give frequencies 20Hz - 20kHz with step 20 Hz. I need 20Hz - 2kHz with step 1 Hz. Can this function do that? If I understand correctly, the documentation suggests a negative answer. Is there any function in python that can do this?

```
fourierSection = 50 #ms
track = wave.open("Vivaldi-Sovente-il-sole.wav", mode="rb")
length = track.getnframes()
frameRate = track.getframerate()
fourierFrames = int(frameRate*fourierSection/1000)
fouriers = 1000;
freqTab = []
for i in range(fouriers):
    data = []
    freqRow = []
    for j in range(fourierFrames):
        waveData = track.readframes(1)
        probe = struct.unpack("<2h", waveData)
        data.append(probe[0])
    dft = np.fft.rfft(data)
    dft = np.absolute(dft)
    for j in range(len(data)//2):
        freqRow.append(np.log2(dft[j]+1))
    freqTab.append(freqRow)
```

I am a newbie in python, so if you have any tips feel free to

Comment: The maximum frequency is given by the sampling frequency, change that to change the range of frequencies output. The frequency step is given by be number of samples. Increase the length of your sampled signal to decrease the frequency steps.

Comment: I don't want to decrese sampling frequency, because I lost accuracy also in lower frequencies. I need change fft output frequencies with this sampling frequency. "Increase the length of your sampled signal to decrease the frequency steps." - I can't do that, because I need this resolution on the timeline. I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. If that's not what you meant, please expand. If I don't find the functionality I need, I do fft myself, but the lack of such basic functionality would be very disappointing.

Comment: This is just how the FFT works. There is no lack of basic functionality, the FFT just does one thing, convert N spatial samples to N frequency samples. If you want a different sampling in the frequency domain you need to modify the sampling of your input signal, everything else is not meaningful. You cannot invent stuff, you have to measure it.